# uUable to use the output of the command "SFC /scannow" in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, converters

What I have done in powershell:

```
$SFC = SFC /scannow

write-output $SFC | out-file d:\cours\powershell\SFC.txt

$string = 'd i d   n o t   f i n d   a n y   i n t e g r i t y   v i o l a t i o n s'

$test = $false
$SFC | foreach {If ($_.name -match $string) {$test = $true}}


if ($test -eq $false)  {write-host 'Ok'}
```

What is in the file 'SFC.txt' is unreadable with notepad++.

More, `$test` is always equal to `$false` (and that's not true).

What to do to save the output correctly in my file in order to be able to read it and what to do for testing this output?

Comment: Be sure tbat before posting this issue, I have tried all the options of the parameter encoding.

-encoding ASCII is not the trick.

I can only read correctly the output on the console with the write-host command. That's all.

In addition, I am unable to find any string in the ouput of this stupid command "SFC /scannow".

That's very strange. when I change the command "SFC" by an other (for example: DIR), The script works like a charm.

You can verify yourself but you must run powershell ise as an administrator.

What is the diference between SFC command and all others?

Answer (score 0):

`Out-File` defaults to writing in Unicode. You can you change that with `-Encoding ASCII`.

You can also use `Set-Content` which defaults to ASCII.

You might also be able to tell Notepad++ to interpret the file as Unicode, but I'm not familiar with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure tbat before posting this issue, I have tried all the options of the parameter encoding.

-encoding ASCII is not the trick.

I can  only read correctly the output  on the console with the write-host command. That's all.

In addition, I am unable to find any string in the ouput of this stupid command "SFC /scannow".

That's very strange. when I change the command "SFC" by an other (for example: DIR), The script works like a charm.

You can verify  yourself but you must run powershell ise as an administrator.

What is the diference between SFC command and all others?

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this as well and found that `-match` works.  It uses regex, so you can use a period to substitute any single character.

Try:
`$string -match '.f.i.n.d...a.n.y...i.n.t.e.g.r.i.t.y...v.i.o.l.a.t.i.o.n.s.'`

Answer (score 0):

Sfc outputs unicode no bom.  Here's a workaround that deletes nulls and blank lines:

```
(sfc) -replace "`0" | where {$_}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem too... As stated before, SFC outputs UNICODE which is two bytes per character (which is why the output is all spaced out, the first character of every pair is empty, binary 00000000 or in notepad++ it shows as NULL)

To get out of this you have to make powershell expect Unicode (and when you are finished reset it to how it was before)

In my case I was calling SFC /SCANNOW from the command prompt and saving the output to a temp file. I prefer to use tee-object as it shows the output onto the console as well

```
POWERSHELL "$prev = [console]::OutputEncoding"; "[console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode"; "SFC /scannow | Tee-Object -filepath %tempfile%"; "[console]::OutputEncoding = $prev"
```

Tidying this up into a powershell script (and changing the output file to match the question):

```
$prev = [console]::OutputEncoding
[console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode
SFC /scannow | Tee-Object -filepath d:\cours\powershell\SFC.txt
[console]::OutputEncoding = $prev
```

There is a potential flaw in this if SFC crashes - leaving Powershell in Unicode (although this is untested)